# Collapsible FieldSet removes components

Tags: extjs

Can somebody help me to solve the problem, that my collapsible FieldSet won't remove components after collapse out?

Please have a look at my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GtjX3/) (FieldSet "Checkboxes").

I am using Ext JS 4.1 RC1.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what function in your example is suppose to remove components?

Comment: FieldSet "Checkboxes". The collapsible image of the FieldSet is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try RC2: http://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-1-rc-2-released/

Answer (score 0):

try removing nested 'vbox' layout from window's center region & fom

check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/JZx98/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need my checkboxes FieldSet centered. Have you an other solution?